# sc.getRealPath(.) and File.seperator on SDK8 and Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, sdk, tomcat8

I have an application that did run fine on both Windows and Linux using Tomcat's 6 and 7 and SDK's 6 and 7. I setup SDK 8 and Tomcat 8 and when the app runs it now chokes on:

```
public static final String THEME_DIRECTORY = File.separator + "WEB-INF"
                                                + File.separator + "theme"
String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath(requiredPath);
```

as `realPath` returns `null`. It turns out that the following is true:

- `requiredPath` is '\WEB-INF\theme';
- `File.separator` is '\';
- If `requiredPath` is set to '/WEB-INF/theme' then I get the `realPath` back as I would expect.

It seems as if the behaviour has changed and I can no longer use `File.separator`.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have encountered it as well.  I suspect this is a more strict implementation of the servlet spec in Tomcat 8 as opposed to 7.  The javadocs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) seem to indicate that the path parameter is supposed to be a URL fragment, which means it must use forward slashes, not backslashes, which is what you are getting when you use File.separator in a windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of your Apache Tomcat 8.

I figured out the backward slash in method getRealPath() works on latest Tomcat, but it doesnt't on versions prior 8.0.29.